# Creating a shortcut to open Terminal with two panes of Ubuntu running PING?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-terminal

The following command line (for use in a Desktop shortcut or from Run) will open a Windows Terminal window, split into two panes, both running Ubuntu:

```
wt -p "Ubuntu" ; split-pane -p "Ubuntu"
```

Is it possible to add a PING command to the above so I can ping two different IPs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the Windows Terminal command-line arguments [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows), `new-tab` and `split-tab` can both take a `commandline` argument.  I will say, however, that the doc is not entirely clear, since it doesn't follow the "normal" doc standard of putting the commandline at the end of the arguments list.  Seeing that `commandline` is the only only argument *not* preceeded with a `-` or `--`, though, it can be inferred.

So for your example, launching two profiles named "Ubuntu" with each pane pinging a different host should simply be:

`wt new-tab -p "Ubuntu" ping -t host1 ; split-pane ping -t host2`

The `-p` for the `split-pane` isn't even needed, as far as I can tell, since you are splitting that first tab that already specifies the Ubuntu profile.

Of course (and this is mostly for others who find this later), you need to quote the `;` properly if you are using the same command from PowerShell (quote with `` ` `` or Linux (quote with `\`).

Comment: I don't know for sure (and can't test), but I suggest looking to see if the 'Ubuntu' command, itself, takes arguments

Comment: To be clear, "Ubuntu" in this case is the name of a WT profile, defined in its `settings.json`, rather than a command itself.  The command in settings (in my case, at least) is actually `wsl.exe`, although WT also supports dynamically generated profiles for each WSL distro, each PowerShell version, cmd, and Azure.  And yes, the `wsl` command supports passing a commandline to any of its supported Linux distributions as well.